# Table is malformed when opening IBM Notes documents

Tags: lotus-notes, text-formatting, documents

We have an IBM Notes client application where users store all kind of rich text information into notes documents, mostly it is pasted email conversations and some attachments.

this is working fine in most cases but once in a while some documents cannot be opened due to the error "table is malformed"

The database is replicated to different servers and sometimes I can fix the problem by finding the document in a replica and resave it. but for some of the documents the error occur on all replicas.

How can I fix this so that my documents can be opened?

This is the error I get when trying to open the document (the document is never opened)

[image]

I have tried to examine the fields using Ytria but not sure what to change. 
one of the document I just examined is only 2Mb in size but it have 95 fields named body2

[image]

- Not sure if this is relevant but some of the servers are using DAOS and some are not.
- All users and servers are on version 9.0.1
- I can make a new copy of the document but then I have two docs that can't be opened

Comment: I managed to fix my problem by deleting the largest Body2 field using Ytria, I probably lost some paragraphs but we can live with that. I also discovered that my rich text fields are placed within a table in the form. read somehwere that this was a problem in earlier releases. it didn't help to move them outside the table but it may be good to know